# Getting the $x-y$ shadow when setting up a triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have the following question:

> Let D be the region bounded below by the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and above the paraboloid $z=2-x^2-y^2$. Set-up the volume in polar coordinates to get the the volume of D.

Now polar coordinates aside in the solution the shadow they got was $x^2+y^2=1$ ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vstv3.jpg)).

From my understanding to get the shadow I would have to solve the equation $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2-x^2-y^2$
Solving this equation yield a totally different shadow: $x^2+y^2=x^4-4x^2+2x^2y^2+y^4-4y^2+4$

How did they get that? I an well aware the question asks to solve in polar but I don't think that's related to this particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z=2-x^2-y^2=2-(x^2+y^2)=2-z^2$$

$$\implies z^2+z-2=(z+2)(z-1)=0\implies z=-2\text{ or }z=1$$

The first solution suggests $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=-2$, which is impossible (over the real numbers), leaving you with $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$, or specfically $x^2+y^2=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Only solution was to solve in polar where you get $r=1$ which corresponds to the unit circle.